# Science fiction book about reversal of Earth's rotation?

Tags: story-identification

I'm looking for a science fiction book about the reversal of Earth's rotation. I read it in the 1970s, but it could have been written in the '60s.

I remember that the story was told from viewpoint of newspaper reporter, and started with preparations for the impending reversal - such as teaching children how to survive tidal waves in the Pacific. There were other ecological crises, such as sea worms coming ashore, and earthquakes.

I also remember something about a hollowed out mountain, with pods for each person. Humans who were not protected became wild. The survivors had to change their views on relationships, in order to increase genetic diversity again.

The book ends with the reporter looking at the new configuration of the sky thinking it’s a window into God’s something. Living room or parlor, I can’t remember exactly.

Comment: Hi Judy - welcome to SF&F - unfortunately, there isn't a lot of detail in your question, and it might help if you could try filling in some more information: anything from the book cover; any description of the characters; other significant events?

Comment: Thanks for answering. I remember they hollowed out a mountain, developed pods for each person. Book started out with ecological crises, sea worms coming ashore, the tidal waves, earthquakes. The humans who were not protected became wild. The book ends with the reporter looking at the new configuration of the sky thinking it’s a window into God’s something. Living room or parlor, I can’t remember. They also had to change the way they looked at relationships so as to create genetic diversity among the survivors.

Comment: Hi Judy - I've edited in the extra details you've provided. If you think of any more, please edit them into your question. Comments can and will be removed from time to time.

Answer (score 4):

Could be [The HAB Theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_HAB_Theory), by  Allan W. Eckert.

[Kirkus Reviews](https://www.kirkusreviews.com/book-reviews/allan-w-eckert-5/the-hab-theory/) says:

> HAB is feisty 94-year-old Herbert Allen Boardman, who stages a faked presidential assassination attempt in order to alert humanity to some disturbing facts about the earth's rotation. On his death a crack investigative journalist takes up the crusade; while scientists debate the merits of the theory, the presidents of America and Kenya embark on a crash program to salvage essentials before the Antarctic ice cap topples the planet onto a different axis.

Comment: Not the book I was trying to remember but sounds like a great read! Ty for this information!

Comment: Silly them. Everyone knows that Antarctica is already on the bottom. Why would it topple over?